# Detecting collision between rectangles in seperate classes

Tags: java, collision-detection

I've been stuck on this for the past hour, I just can't figure it out.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends BasicGame{
    int px = 100, py = 100;
    Entity eo;
    Rectangle player = new Rectangle(px, py, 16, 16);
```

Update function in the main class:

```
public void update(GameContainer gc, int arg) throws SlickException {
        if(player.intersects(eo.r)){
            System.out.println("Collision");
        }
```

Entity class:

```
public class Entity extends BasicGame{
    int x, y;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, y, 16, 16);

public Entity(String n, int h, int posx, int posy){
        x = posx;
        y = posy;
```

Note: This isn't the real format of the code, I've stripped it of the irrelevant stuff.

The error message I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at src.Main.update(Main.java:49)
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:657)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
    at src.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Mon Dec 19 20:35:23 CST 2011 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
    at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:408)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:318)
    at src.Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is `line 49` of the `Main` class? `NullPointerException` means you're referencing an object that you don't think is `null`. This shouldn't have anything to do with collision detection itself.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException probably indicates that either `player` (was initialized) or `eo` is null. Indeed I do not see

```
eo = new Entity();
```

Furthermore `new Rectangle(x, y, 16, 16)` above is equivalent with 0, 0, 16, 16. And afterwards assigning to x or y will not change the player Rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The line "player.intersects(eo.r)" is particularly suspicious and prone to causing this error.  I'm assuming that thus is line 49.

The accession of multiple internal variables without checking if they are correctly set is usually a hotspot for NullPointerExceptions in java.

Thus either "player" is null, eo is null, or r is null, OR the intersects() method is returning nul.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(player.intersects(eo.r))
```

This is not a good code. You should replace it with checking if both player and eo are not nulls, i.e. something like this:

```
if(eo != null && eo != null && player.intersects(eo.r))
```